# Why BitBucketSourceAction is removed from cdk v2 version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am using AWS cdk to deploy codebuild and use `BitBucketSourceAction` class to build bitbucket source stage in the codepipeline. Below is the code I am using when using cdk v1. But after upgrading to cdk v2, I can't find this class from the library `aws-cdk-lib`. How can I build a bitbucket source stage from V2?

```
import * as actions from '@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions';
...

      stageName: 'Source',
      actions: [
        new actions.BitBucketSourceAction({
          actionName: 'SourceAction',
          owner: owner,
          connectionArn: connectionArn,
          branch: branchName,
          output:sourceOutput,
          repo: bitbucketName,
        }),
      ],
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs from the 1.x version You should use *CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction* instead of *BitBucketSourceAction* because it is deprecated. The CDK 2.x major version removed all the deprecated packages from the *aws-cdk-lib* package.

Here the references:

[BitBucket deprecated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codepipeline-actions.BitBucketSourceAction.html)

[Use this implementation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction.html)

[Migrating to CDK v2:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/migrating-v2.html)

> Deprecated properties, methods, and types in AWS CDK v1.x and its Construct Library have been removed completely from the CDK v2 API. In most supported languages, these APIs produce warnings under v1.x, so you may have already migrated to the replacement APIs. A complete list of deprecated APIs in CDK v1.x is available on GitHub.